# Algorithm to split the values of a list into a specific format

Tags: python, list, split, recursive-query

Can you help me with my algorithm in Python to parse a list, please?

```py
List = ['PPPP_YYYY_ZZZZ_XXXX', 'PPPP_TOTO_TATA_TITI_TUTU', 'PPPP_TOTO_MMMM_TITI_TUTU', 'PPPP_TOTO_EHEH_TITI_TUTU', 'PPPP_TOTO_EHEH_OOOO_AAAAA', 'PPPP_TOTO_EHEH_IIII_SSSS_RRRR']
```

In this list, I have to get the last two words (PARENT_CHILD). For example for `PPPP_TOTO_TATA_TITI_TUTU`, I only get `TITI_TUTU`

In the case where there are duplicates, that is to say that in my list, I have: `PPPP_TOTO_TATA_TITI_TUTU` and `PPPP_TOTO_EHEH_TITI_TUTU`, I would have two times `TITI_TUTU`, I then want to recover the GRANDPARENT for each of them, that is: `TATA_TITI_TUTU` and `EHEH_TITI_TUTU`
As long as the names are duplicated, we take the level above.

But in this case, if I added the GRANDPARENT for `EHEH_TITI_TUTU`, I also want it to be added for all those who have `EHEH` in the name so instead of having `OOOO_AAAAA`, I would like to have `EHEH_OOO_AAAAA` and `EHEH_IIII_SSSS_RRRR`

My final list =

```py
['ZZZZ_XXXX', 'TATA_TITI_TUTU', 'MMMM_TITI_TUTU', 'EHEH_TITI_TUTU', 'EHEH_OOOO_AAAAA', 'EHEH_IIII_SSSS_RRRR']
```

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I started to write:

```
json_paths = ['PPPP_YYYY_ZZZZ_XXXX', 'PPPP_TOTO_TATA_TITI_TUTU', 
'PPPP_TOTO_EHEH_TITI_TUTU', 'PPPP_TOTO_MMMM_TITI_TUTU', 'PPPP_TOTO_EHEH_OOOO_AAAAA']

cols_name = []
for path in json_paths:
    acc=2
    col_name = '_'.join(path.split('_')[-acc:])
    tmp = cols_name
    while col_name in tmp:
        acc += 1
        idx = tmp.index(col_name)
        cols_name[idx] = '_'.join(json_paths[idx].split('_')[-acc:])
        col_name = '_'.join(path.split('_')[-acc:])
        tmp = ['_'.join(item.split('_')[-acc:]) for item in json_paths].pop()
    cols_name.append(col_name)
    print(cols_name.index(col_name), col_name)

cols_name
```

Comment: Will it stop at the grandparent level, or the same logic should apply (when needed) to the upper levels as well?

Comment: @gimix: Indeed, the same logic should apply to the upper level if the GRANDPARENT_PARENT_CHILD are not different. As long as the names are duplicated, we take the level above

Comment: You have a number of rules/requirements and you have a solution. Which part of the rules are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

> help ... with ... algorithm

- use a dictionary for the initial container while iterating

  - keys will be `PARENT_CHILD`'s and values will be lists containing grandparents.

```
    >>> s = 'PPPP_TOTO_TATA_TITI_TUTU'
    >>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    >>> *_,grandparent,parent,child = s.rsplit('_',maxsplit=3)
    >>> d['_'.join([parent,child])].append(grandparent)
    >>> d
    defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'TITI_TUTU': ['TATA']})
    >>> s = 'PPPP_TOTO_EHEH_TITI_TUTU'   
    >>> *_,grandparent,parent,child = s.rsplit('_',maxsplit=3)
    >>> d['_'.join([parent,child])].append(grandparent)
    >>> d
    defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'TITI_TUTU': ['TATA', 'EHEH']})
    >>>
```

- after iteration determine if there are multiple grandparents in a value

  - if there are, join/append the parent_child to each grandparent

    - additionally find all the parent_child's with these grandparents and prepend their grandparents. To facilitate *build* a second dictionary during iteration  - `{grandparent:[list_of_children],...}`.
  - if the parent_child only has one grandparent use as-is

---

Instead of splitting each string the info could be extracted with a regular expression.

```
pattern = r'^.*?_([^_]*)_([^_]*_[^_]*)$'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But grandparent will change because as long as the names are duplicated, we take the level above.

Comment: Ahh, well maybe reverse the mapping to `{parent_child:[grandparent,grandparent,...]}`

Comment: See edit. .....

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. I did what you suggested, can you see the comment just below